# Marking classes and/or methods as deprecated in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, deprecated

Is there any way to mark a class and/or method as deprecated in Sphinx? I can only find a deprecated option for modules.

Using a generic admonition would work, but wouldn't carry the semantic meaning.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`deprecated`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-deprecated).

Comment: This doesn't work when using Google Style with Napoleon.ext

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use the [deprecation](https://pypi.org/project/deprecation/) module.

It offers a decorator to mark your class/function as deprecated. This will not only produce a deprecation warning when the class / function is used, but also generate the right paragraph in sphinx.